# ListView setOnItemClick issue

Tags: android, android-listview

So I am making a `Listview` using my custom adapter. The adapter layout is shown below

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I set `onItemClickListener` to the `ListView` and it is doing fine. Then when I added a button to the layout become

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the `ListView` is no longer clickable. What I want to achieve is when I click on the ListView will show profile description. then when I tap on the button, it will lead to profile edit activity.

Comment: your button tag is not ended properly its missing the end tag />

Comment: Do you want to handle the button click listener of the listitem? What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: I have add what I want to achieve. Sorry.

Comment: Have tried by creating the adapter of the list and in adapter have you handled the click of the button ?

Comment: No I haven't create a handler when the button is clicked. But anyway both listview and button are now clickable. The solution is given by Gopinath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check if the button is taking away all the clicks generated on the row?

Try to restrict the button touch area to a piece of the row or try setting `android:focusable="false"` for the button if you wish the button to be not clickable.

Comment: I am going to try your solution.

Comment: Thank you Gopinath, now both ListView and the Button are clickable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typing mistake, or you forgot to close the Button?

Comment: Ya I forgot to close the tag when I type my question. It does have a close tag.

Answer (score 1):

modify like this:

```
<Button
    android:text="edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. I forgot to close the tag. And it is not the cause of my issue.